# jboss as 7 Unable to connect to oracle 11.2.0.1.0

Tags: java, jdbc, jboss, oracle11gr2

I am on jboss as 7 and i defined an oracle datasouce to oracle 11.2.0.1.0
when i use sql developer to connect to this database it works but throuw jboss it's impossible i've got this error

[org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (HttpManagementService-threads - 4) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get

```
a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:277) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:235) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:761) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:343) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:397) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:365) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.internalTestConnection(AbstractPool.java:627) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool.testConnection(OnePool.java:88) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.pool.PoolOperations$TestConnectionInPool.invokeCommandOn(PoolOperations.java:121) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.pool.PoolOperations$1.execute(PoolOperations.java:60) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.pool.PoolOperations.execute(PoolOperations.java:74) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$DefaultPrepareStepHandler.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:466) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:121) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:309) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$1.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:299) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.processRequest(DomainApiHandler.java:294)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.doHandle(DomainApiHandler.java:201)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.DomainApiHandler.handle(DomainApiHandler.java:208)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.SubjectAssociationHandler.handle(SubjectAssociationHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.AuthFilter.doFilter(AuthFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange$LinkHandler.handle(ServerImpl.java:710)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:78)
    at org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.RealmReadinessFilter.doFilter(RealmReadinessFilter.java:54)
    at org.jboss.com.sun.net.httpserver.Filter$Chain.doFilter(Filter.java:81)
    at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$Exchange.run(ServerImpl.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Erreur d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:249) [ironjacamar-jdbc-1.0.9.Final.jar:1.0.9.Final]
    ... 39 more
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:439)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:454)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:693)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:251)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1140)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:340)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:149)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:133)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:405)
    ... 49 more
```

here is my standalone.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">


-<extensions>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>

<extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>

</extensions>


-<management>


-<security-realms>


-<security-realm name="ManagementRealm">


-<authentication>

<properties relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" path="mgmt-users.properties"/>

</authentication>

</security-realm>


-<security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">


-<authentication>

<properties relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" path="application-users.properties"/>

</authentication>

</security-realm>

</security-realms>


-<management-interfaces>


-<native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">

<socket-binding native="management-native"/>

</native-interface>


-<http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">

<socket-binding http="management-http"/>

</http-interface>

</management-interfaces>

</management>


-<profile>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">


-<console-handler name="CONSOLE">

<level name="INFO"/>


-<formatter>

<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>

</formatter>

</console-handler>


-<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">


-<formatter>

<pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>

</formatter>

<file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>

<suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>

<append value="true"/>

</periodic-rotating-file-handler>


-<logger category="com.arjuna">

<level name="WARN"/>

</logger>


-<logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">

<level name="WARN"/>

</logger>


-<logger category="sun.rmi">

<level name="WARN"/>

</logger>


-<logger category="jacorb">

<level name="WARN"/>

</logger>


-<logger category="jacorb.config">

<level name="ERROR"/>

</logger>


-<root-logger>

<level name="INFO"/>


-<handlers>

<handler name="CONSOLE"/>

<handler name="FILE"/>

</handlers>

</root-logger>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">


-<datasources>


-<datasource use-java-context="true" enabled="true" pool-name="ExampleDS" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS">

<connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>

<driver>h2</driver>


-<security>

<user-name>sa</user-name>

<password>sa</password>

</security>

</datasource>


-<datasource enabled="true" pool-name="Argos" jndi-name="java:/Argos" use-ccm="false" jta="false">

<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.61.1:1521:SID</connection-url>

<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>

<driver>OracleJDBCDriver</driver>


-<security>

<user-name>argos14</user-name>

<password>oracle</password>

</security>


-<validation>

<validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>

<background-validation>false</background-validation>

</validation>


-<statement>

<share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>

</statement>

</datasource>


-<drivers>


-<driver module="com.h2database.h2" name="h2">

<xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>

</driver>

<driver module="com.oracle.jdbc" name="OracleJDBCDriver"/>

<driver module="org.postgresql" name="postgres"/>

</drivers>

</datasources>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">

<deployment-scanner relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" scan-interval="5000"/>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">


-<session-bean>


-<stateless>

<bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>

</stateless>

<stateful cache-ref="simple" default-access-timeout="5000"/>

<singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>

</session-bean>


-<pools>


-<bean-instance-pools>

<strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" max-pool-size="20"/>

<strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" max-pool-size="20"/>

</bean-instance-pools>

</pools>


-<caches>

<cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>

<cache name="passivating" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache" passivation-store-ref="file"/>

</caches>


-<passivation-stores>

<file-passivation-store name="file"/>

</passivation-stores>

<async thread-pool-name="default"/>


-<timer-service thread-pool-name="default">

<data-store relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" path="timer-service-data"/>

</timer-service>

<remote thread-pool-name="default" connector-ref="remoting-connector"/>


-<thread-pools>


-<thread-pool name="default">

<max-threads count="10"/>

<keepalive-time unit="milliseconds" time="100"/>

</thread-pool>

</thread-pools>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">


-<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">


-<local-cache name="entity">

<transaction mode="NON_XA"/>

<eviction max-entries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>

<expiration max-idle="100000"/>

</local-cache>


-<local-cache name="local-query">

<transaction mode="NONE"/>

<eviction max-entries="10000" strategy="LRU"/>

<expiration max-idle="100000"/>

</local-cache>


-<local-cache name="timestamps">

<transaction mode="NONE"/>

<eviction strategy="NONE"/>

</local-cache>

</cache-container>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">

<archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-warn="false" fail-on-error="true"/>

<bean-validation enabled="true"/>


-<default-workmanager>


-<short-running-threads>

<core-threads count="50"/>

<queue-length count="50"/>

<max-threads count="50"/>

<keepalive-time unit="seconds" time="10"/>

</short-running-threads>


-<long-running-threads>

<core-threads count="50"/>

<queue-length count="50"/>

<max-threads count="50"/>

<keepalive-time unit="seconds" time="10"/>

</long-running-threads>

</default-workmanager>

<cached-connection-manager/>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">

<show-model value="true"/>

<remoting-connector/>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">

<jpa default-datasource=""/>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">


-<mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">

<smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>

</mail-session>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">


-<properties>

<property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning"> 1 </property>

</properties>


-<capabilities>

<capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>

<capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>

<capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>

<capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>

<capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>

<capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>

</capabilities>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">

<connector name="remoting-connector" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" socket-binding="remoting"/>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">


-<security-domains>


-<security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">


-<authentication>


-<login-module flag="optional" code="Remoting">

<module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>

</login-module>


-<login-module flag="required" code="RealmUsersRoles">

<module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>

<module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>

<module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>

<module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>

</login-module>

</authentication>

</security-domain>


-<security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">


-<authorization>

<policy-module flag="required" code="Delegating"/>

</authorization>

</security-domain>


-<security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">


-<authorization>

<policy-module flag="required" code="Delegating"/>

</authorization>

</security-domain>

</security-domains>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">


-<core-environment>


-<process-id>

<uuid/>

</process-id>

</core-environment>

<recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>

<coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" native="false" default-virtual-server="default-host">

<connector name="http" socket-binding="http" scheme="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1"/>


-<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">

<alias name="localhost"/>

<alias name="example.com"/>

</virtual-server>

</subsystem>


-<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">

<modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>

<wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>

<endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>


-<endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">


-<pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">

<handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>

</pre-handler-chain>

</endpoint-config>

</subsystem>

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>

</profile>


-<interfaces>


-<interface name="management">

<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>

</interface>


-<interface name="public">

<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>

</interface>


-<interface name="unsecure">

<inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>

</interface>

</interfaces>


-<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}" default-interface="public">

<socket-binding name="management-native" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}" interface="management"/>

<socket-binding name="management-http" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}" interface="management"/>

<socket-binding name="management-https" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}" interface="management"/>

<socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>

<socket-binding name="http" port="80"/>

<socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>

<socket-binding name="osgi-http" port="8090" interface="management"/>

<socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>

<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>

<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>


-<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">

<remote-destination port="25" host="localhost"/>

</outbound-socket-binding>

</socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

and my module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.oracle.jdbc">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Telnet is OK on 1521

and sql developer can connect from the same pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I resolved with putting  xa-datasource-class on `<drivers>` in standalone.xml

```
<driver name="OracleJDBCDriver" module="com.oracle.jdbc">
<xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>

</driver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case, the DB user was locked so I had to alter the user by the following command and it worked.

Command-> alter user [username] identified by [password] account unlock;

To check how it was locked just do

1. sqlplus and hit enter
2. it will prompt your DB's username and password enter the DB username and password
3. then it will tell you that the account is locked